# Prove $(0\le a\lt b)\Rightarrow (0\le\sqrt{a}\lt\sqrt{b})$. Why is the proof of $0\le\sqrt{a}$ not needed?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

$(0\le a\lt b)\implies(0\le\sqrt{a}\lt\sqrt{b})$

According to a proof by contradiction,

Why is the proof of $0\le\sqrt{a}$ not needed?

Proof:

If

> $ (\sqrt{a}\ge\sqrt{b})$

then

> $a = (\sqrt{a})^2 \ge (\sqrt{b})^2 = b$

A contradiction

Comment: $\sqrt a $ stands for the non-negative square root of $a$. That is a  convention in Mathematics.

Comment: Note that "If $x\ge y$, then $x^2\ge y^2$" is not true in general. Here, knowing that $x=\sqrt{a}$ and $y=\sqrt{b}$ are nonnegative is important.

Comment: @Taladris Do you mean the converse of the proof in the title?
I have no doubt the goal of the proof. 
I don't understand why some part of the goal is not shown.

Comment: Hope my answer here helps to solve your problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4863352/1277478

Comment: @VinayKarthik Brilliant!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 \le \sqrt{a}$ is true for all $a$, by definition of $\sqrt{\cdot}$. (This depends on your definition of $\sqrt{\cdot}$, but I know it as a function $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$; since you're dealing with inequalities anyway, that means we can't be in $\mathbb{C}$.)