# In writing a proof how are we certain whether some part of a goal in the proof can be ignored or not?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I ask this question because I probably meet the same obstacle when writing other proofs.

In writing a proof

My example would be

$(0\le a\lt b)\implies(0\le\sqrt{a}\lt\sqrt{b})$

The goal is $(0\le\sqrt{a}\lt\sqrt{b})$

But here the $0\le\sqrt{a}$ is like an assumption or a definition

So the proof of $0\le\sqrt{a}$ is ignored

Could we add these extra assumptions or definitions in the proof in order to make our proofs more readable?

How are we certain whether some part of a goal in the proof can be ignored or not?

I asked this proof before which is from the instructor's solutions manual of a textbook.

[image: Picture of the proof from a book]

[Same proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862683/prove-0-le-a-lt-b-rightarrow-0-le-sqrta-lt-sqrtb-why-is-the-proof-of/4862687#4862687)

Comment: You cannot "ignore" the proof of $0\le \sqrt{a}$, even if it follows by definition. In your proof you can start by saying, why  and how it follows from a definition (which one?). This counts as a proof, even if it is a trivial one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Does an instructor's solutions manual sometimes provide incomplete proof?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I asked that question with the same proof which does not prove the whole inequality.

Comment: Sometimes , Solutions given in the text books are more like hints , not necessarily complete ! Students have to use the given outline to fill in the Details !

Comment: Attention to Detail : Previous Comment was made by me.

Comment: @Prem Thank you. I was so worried about my comprehension in proving mathematical problems

Comment: Letting you know that the accepted answer is unfortunately wrong. Consider $-4 < -1$ : Can we claim $-4 < -1 \implies \sqrt{-4} < \sqrt{-1}$ ? NO ! We need "ZERO" on LHS to "limit" the Square root !

Comment: I thought $a < b => √a < √b$ is derived after we reached the contradiction. 
So $a < b => √a < √b$ is used. But I am not quite sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the proof $a < b => √a < √b$ is sufficient to prove your question.

Just take $a = 0$ and $b = a$ for proving $0 < a => 0 < √a$ in the above statement. For the equality case $a = 0$, the proof is trivial as $√a = 0$.

I think the book should mention explicitly what they are trying to do.

Comment: Oh , unfortunately this is wrong. Consider $-1 < +4$ : Can we claim $-1 < +4 \implies \sqrt{-1} < \sqrt{+4}$ ? We need $0$ on LHS to "limit" the Square root !